# vim plugin delimitmate doesn't work with tex file. Is there any other plugin for autoclose working fine with vim-latex?

Tags: vim, vim-latex

I often use delimitmate plugin for autoclose. It works well in other file types except tex file.

In other file type such txt, when I typeset `(`, I will get `()` with the cursor between the parenthesis. However, in the tex file, nothing happens.

I have found someone having the same problem:
https://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate/issues/48. It turns out that delimitmate conflicts with vim-latex suit.

Is there any other plugin for autoclose working fine with vim-latex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and asked this exact same question on here a couple of weeks ago. There were no answers and so I finally deleted my question.

**Here is what I did as a workaround.**

I also installed the vim plugin
[`auto-close`](https://github.com/Townk/vim-autoclose). This resolved my problem as far as automatically closing parenthesis, square braces etc were concerned. But then some of the `ctrl-j` functionality of `vim-latex-suite` gets disabled after that. But I can live with it. I actually find the place holder markers annoying. The only reason I use `vim-latex-suite` is to use `,ll` and `,lv` and forward searching and inverse searching capabilities.

This is perhaps not a complete solution to your problem, but it certainly worked for me. I also use the package `snipmate` in writing my `.tex` documents in latex. So there really is no need for all the fancy placeholder stuff that you get in `vim-latex-suite`. Hope that helps. Btw, my leader key is set to `,`

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks very much. `ctrl-j` is useful for environment, but annoying sometimes. I have to do that trade-off. I think that giving up autoclose maybe OK. Besides, I use vim-latex-suite for another reason that I can use it on win7 with gvim.